# Como bloquear temporalmente la propiedad onclick de imágenes en una lista?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con HTML, CSS y JavaScript. En dicho proyecto tengo una lista de imágenes a las cuales puedo hacerle clic y así, agregarlas a un box o contenedor nuevo. 
El siguiente código hace dicha funcionalidad:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="image"]').forEach(function(image) {
  var imagen;
  image.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    reportList.push(this); //pone imagenes en lista
    console.log(reportList);
    imagen = y.appendChild(this.cloneNode()); //pone imagenes en contenedor
    if (z.style.display == "none") { 
      z.style.display = "block"; //muestra botón agregar
    }
  });
});
```

Además, tengo un boton agregar que hace que se despliegue dicho contenedor, mostrando las imágenes elegidas. El IF del anterior código hace desaparecer este botón para que el usuario no pueda agregar mas imagenes.

El problema con esto es que el usuario aun puede seguir agregando imágenes al contenedor haciendo clic en las mismas. Como evito esto? intente ponerle la propiedad on clic en nulo pero no funciono. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu código debes usar `removeEventListener` para deshabilitar el evento click pero para que te funcione tanto para el `addEventListener` y el `removeEventListener` deben de llamar a la misma función, si lo pones por separado no te va a funcionar, ejemplo de como no debe ser:

```js
var agregar = document.getElementById("agregar");

document.getElementById("deshabilitar").addEventListener("click", () => {
  agregar.removeEventListener("click",() => {
    alert("Click eliminado");
  },true); 
});

agregar.addEventListener("click", () => {
 alert("Hola");
},true);
```

```html
<button id="agregar">Agregar Imagen</button>
<button id="deshabilitar">Deshabilitar Click</button>
```

Como veras si presionar deshabilitar aun sigue haciendo el alert, pero si ahora le colocamos la misma función:

```js
var agregar = document.getElementById("agregar");
const mensaje = (e) => {
  alert("Hola");
}

document.getElementById("deshabilitar").addEventListener("click", () => {
  agregar.removeEventListener("click",mensaje,true); 
});

document.getElementById("habilitar").addEventListener("click", () => {
  agregar.addEventListener("click", mensaje,true);
});

agregar.addEventListener("click", mensaje,true);
```

```html
<button id="agregar">Agregar Imagen</button>
<button id="habilitar">Habilitar Click</button>
<button id="deshabilitar">Deshabilitar Click</button>
```

Espero te sirva.